# $\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}(1−u_0(x))\sin(x/2)(\delta(x + π) + \delta(x−π))\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

[image: Intgral from -2π− 2π of (1−u0(x))sin(x/2)(δ(x + π) + δ(x−π))dx]

Im not sure where to begin with this, or what formula or theory is being tested. any suggestions to what method I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can use this property of $\delta$: $\displaystyle\int_{-a}^af(x)\delta(x-t)dx=f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Break the integral in two using linearity, and find that 
$$
\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi}(1-u_0(x))\sin(x)\delta(x-\pi)\mathrm dx=(1-u_0(\pi))\sin(\pi)=0
$$
the other piece is similar.